# How to adjust the width of a wrap text sideways column header in tabular

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow, wrap, multicolumn

I am trying to create table as below, in Texmaker.

[image]

here i am facing following issues.

1. To wrap text the column headers from 4 to 6 and align it center.
2. Hspace on paragraph [row 3 last column] is not working
3. Last multirow contains a element from its earlier row.

screen shot below. issues are highlighted in red box

[image]

Below is the complete code... Please help me to resolve these issues.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{color, textcomp, listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'All Exp Table'
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|m{.5 cm}|m {.5 cm}|m{.5 cm}|m {10.5 cm}|}
\hline
    {\begin{sideways} {\centering { Rule No} } \end{sideways}}& {\begin{sideways} {\centering { F\_offsetFlag } } \end{sideways}} & {\begin{sideways} {\centering { B\_offsetFlag } } \end{sideways}} &      \multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { F\_offsetDiff Relation  MaxBlkSize} \end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { B\_offsetDiff (Relation) MaxBlkSize} \end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { F\_offsetDiff (Relation) B\_offsetDiff } \end{sideways}} &  {\textbf{Action}} \\     \hline
1     & F     & F     & $<$     &  & =     & \pbox{10 cm}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null);} \\ \hline
2     & F     & F     & =     & {} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l} { \pbox{10 cm}{If (hasBlockHashOnHBase(next\_b\_hash)) \\ \hspace{1 cm} byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(f\_buf, 0, (int)(b\_offset-offset)); \\ \hspace{1 cm} recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null); \\
Else \\ WriteBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null); } }\\ \hline
3     & F     & F     &       & = & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_buf,b\_hash,null);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
4     & F     & F     &       & {=} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
5     & F     & T     &       & {$<$} & =     & \pbox{10 cm}{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize), b\_buf.length); \\
recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets (buf,null,b\_hash+","+(maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length);} \\ \hline
6     & F     & T     &       & {$<$} &       & \pbox{10 cm}{If (offset==0)\\
IncrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_hash,b\_BlkSize);\\
Else\\
byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize), b\_buf.length);\\
recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,b\_hash+","+ (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length); } \\ \hline

9     & T     & F     & $<$     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
10    & T     & F     & =     & {} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
11    & T     & F     & =     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{10 cm}{{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, 0, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize));\\ recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null);\\ incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}}} \\ \cline{1-6}
12    & T     & F     & $>$     & {} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
13    & T     & T     & $<$     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
14    & T     & T     & =     & {} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{}
  \label{tab:ImplLogic2}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

===============================================

## my second code (after solving first two issue)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{color, textcomp, listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'All Exp Table'
\begin{table}[!htbp]

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|m{1.3 cm}| m{1.3 cm}|m{1.3 cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{8.8 cm}|}
\hline

\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2 cm}{\centering Rule No}}&
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2 cm}{\centering F\_offsetFlag}}&
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2 cm}{\centering B\_offsetFlag}}&
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.2 cm}{\centering F\_offsetDiff (Relation) MaxBlkSize}}&
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.2 cm}{\centering B\_offsetDiff (Relation) MaxBlkSize}}&
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.2 cm}{\centering F\_offsetDiff (Relation) B\_offsetDiff}}& 
{\centering {\textbf{Action}}} \\
    \hline
1     & F     & F     & \centering$<$     &  & \centering =     & {writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null);} \\ \hline
2     & F     & F     & \centering =     &  & \centering$>$     &  {If (hasBlockHashOnHBase(next\_b\_hash)) \\ \hspace*{.2 cm}byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(f\_buf, 0, (int)(b\_offset-offset)); \\ \hspace*{.2 cm}recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null); \\ Else \\ \hspace*{.2 cm}writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null); } \\ \hline
3     & F     & F     &       & \centering = & \centering =     & {\multirow{2}[4]{*}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_buf,b\_hash,null);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
4     & F     & F     &       & \centering = & \centering $>$     &  \\ \hline
5     & F     & T     &       & \centering $<$ & \centering =     & \pbox{8.8 cm}{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize), b\_buf.length); \\
recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets (buf,null,b\_hash+","+(maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length);} \\ \hline
6     & F     & T     &       & \centering $<$ &       & \pbox{8.8 cm}{If (offset==0)\\
\hspace*{.2 cm}IncrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets (b\_hash,b\_BlkSize);\\
Else\\
\hspace*{.2 cm}byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-    lastBlkSize),b\_buf.length);\\
\hspace*{.2 cm}recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets (buf,null,b\_hash+","+(maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length); } \\ \hline

9     & T     & F     & \centering $<$     &  & \centering =     & {\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
10    & T     & F     & \centering =     &  &       &  \\ \hline
11    & T     & F     & \centering =     &  & \centering =     & {\multirow{2}[4]{8.8 cm}{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, 0, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize));\\     recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null);\\     incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
12    & T     & F     & \centering $>$     &  &       &  \\ \hline
13    & T     & T     & \centering $<$     &  & \centering =   & {\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
14    & T     & T     & \centering =     &  & \centering $>$ &  \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}%
\caption{}
  \label{tab:ImplLogic2}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

The current file output pasted below, issues are highlighted in red box
[image]

Comment: Hmm, for something this complicated, I'd draw the structure using `tikz` instead. This gives a lot more control, and one does not end up with such messy code

Answer (score 4):

You don't really want `rotating` which is mainly for the `sdewatstable` package (the `sideways` environment is really just for compatibility with the LaTeX2.09 version syntax)
You just need `graphicx` (which `rotating` usues internally anyway) then

```
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering B\_offsetDiff (Relation) MaxBlkSize}
```

or

```
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}B\_offsetDiff\\ (Relation)\\ MaxBlkSize\end{tabular}}
```

Also you last column is very spaced out use

```
 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{10.5cm}
```

so the column is set ragged right. (delete `\pbox` you do not need it here)

```
\\ \hspace{1 cm}
```

white space is always discarded at the start of a line use the star form `\hspace*{1cm}` to keep it.

I'm not sure what you intend with multirow but

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multicolumn
```

looks wrong, I suspect you don't want the outer \multicolumn`

Comment: Thanks @ David Carlisle. It resolved my first issue. Any idea how to solve the following issues.  2.Hspace on paragraph [row 3 last column] is not working; 3. Last multirow contains a element from its earlier row.

Comment: [I am new to this community] Do i need to ask other issues as a separate question?

Comment: @Krishnaprasad I have updated the answer but it is best if you do not ask three questions in one, and best if you ask followup questions as new questions, but welcome to the site!

Comment: @ DavidCarlisle Thank you. This time \hspace*{1cm} resolved the 2nd issue. But the problem "Last multirow contains a element from its earlier row" still persists. I removed \multicolumn{1}{l} option from all cells (which came from Excel2Latex tool), but couldn't able to remove '\pbox' from cells, it giving an error message "! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.28 ...lockHashOnHBase(next\_b\_hash)) \\ \hspace". The '\centering' option within '\rotatebox{90}' also not working. I am not sure how i can paste my current code. Also is there any option to left shift the complete table.

Comment: I have edited question with latest code and output screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I got the complete solution on an another post. Please refer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132512/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-a-wrap-text-sideways-column-header-and-width-of-a-par/133108?iemail=1&noredirect=1#133108. Once again Thank you.