# How to adjust the width of a wrap text sideways column header and width of a paragraph cell in tabular

Tags: wrap, multicolumn, tables, multirow

I am trying to create table as below, in Texmaker.

[image].

here i am facing following issues.

1. To wrap text the column headers from 4 to 6 and align it center.
2. Hspace on paragraph [row 3 last column] is not working
3. Last multirow contains a element from its earlier row.

screen shot below. issues are highlighted in **red** box

[image]

Below is the complete code... Please help me to resolve these issues.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{color, textcomp, listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'All Exp Table'
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
      \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|m{.5 cm}|m {.5 cm}|m{.5 cm}|m {10.5 cm}|}
\hline
    {\begin{sideways} {\centering { Rule No} } \end{sideways}}& {\begin{sideways} {\centering { F\_offsetFlag } } \end{sideways}} & {\begin{sideways} {\centering { B\_offsetFlag } } \end{sideways}} &      \multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { F\_offsetDiff Relation  MaxBlkSize} \end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { B\_offsetDiff (Relation) MaxBlkSize} \end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{m {.5 cm}}{\begin{sideways} { F\_offsetDiff (Relation) B\_offsetDiff } \end{sideways}} &  {\textbf{Action}} \\     \hline
    1     & F     & F     & $<$     &  & =     & \pbox{10 cm}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null);} \\ \hline
    2     & F     & F     & =     & {} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l} { \pbox{10 cm}{If (hasBlockHashOnHBase(next\_b\_hash)) \\ \hspace{1 cm} byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(f\_buf, 0, (int)(b\_offset-offset)); \\ \hspace{1 cm} recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null); \\
Else \\ WriteBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null); } }\\ \hline
    3     & F     & F     &       & = & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_buf,b\_hash,null);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
    4     & F     & F     &       & {=} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
    5     & F     & T     &       & {$<$} & =     & \pbox{10 cm}{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize), b\_buf.length); \\
recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets (buf,null,b\_hash+","+(maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length);} \\ \hline
    6     & F     & T     &       & {$<$} &       & \pbox{10 cm}{If (offset==0)\\
   IncrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_hash,b\_BlkSize);\\
Else\\
   byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize), b\_buf.length);\\
   recordSuperBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,b\_hash+","+ (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize)+","+buf.length); } \\ \hline

    9     & T     & F     & $<$     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
    10    & T     & F     & =     & {} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
    11    & T     & F     & =     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{10 cm}{{byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, 0, (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize));\\ recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null);\\ incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}}} \\ \cline{1-6}
    12    & T     & F     & $>$     & {} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
    13    & T     & T     & $<$     & {} & =     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}} \\ \cline{1-6}
    14    & T     & T     & =     & {} & $>$     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{}
  \label{tab:ImplLogic2}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many questions here.

First a comment: when you use `\multicolumn` remember to include any rules that are needed, e.g. write `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` instead of a plain `c`.  Withouth the `|` you vertical lines will have holes.

For the rotated labels, it is best to treat them all the same.  Your first 6 columns can all be of type `c`.  Now the label needs to be centered in a box and rotated.  It is easiest to make all these boxes of one fixed width before rotation, so the same centering is being applied.  So my suggestion is to create a commond to do all of this and introduce a length you can adjust.  The following command `\sidewaysc` can be used simply as `\sidewaysc{Text\\ text}`:

```
\newlength{\sidewaysclen}
\setlength{\sidewaysclen}{6em}

\newcommand{\sidewaysc}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\sidewaysclen}{%
  \begin{sideways}\begin{minipage}{\sidewaysclen}%
    \centering #1\end{minipage}\end{sideways}}}
```

The `sideways` environment rotates the box about a corner, for your table it is best to move it down via the `\raisebox` so that it is centered on the line.

The missing `\hspace`s are due to the enclosing enviroment implicitly used.  It is essentialy a paragraph, and if you specify a line break in a paragraph, LaTeX will ignore the space at the beginning of the next line.  There several ways around this.  If you pack the material up in a `\parbox` and specify `\raggedright` then the `\hspace`s will be honoured.  I suggest you use `\quad` and `\qquad` for these spaces, they are equal to `\hspace{1em}` and `\hspace{2em}`, but easier to use consistently.  Incidentally a `\multirow` with a specified width already packs its argument this way with `\raggedright` (at least in the default set-up), so such spacing is honoured there.  In the example below I have introduced a length variable to specify the width of the final column and used each time I need to specify a `\parbox` or `\multirow` width in that column.

Finally, the "repeated" text at the bottom is a `\multirow` overlapping the next row of the table.  The `\multirow` command does nothing to provide the need vertical space, so you should widen the corresponding rows, e.g. by using `\\[dimension]`.  In your case you want to do this evenly on two consecutive rows, `\\[4ex]` seems about right.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\sidewaysclen}
\setlength{\sidewaysclen}{6em}
\newcommand{\sidewaysc}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\sidewaysclen}{%
  \begin{sideways}\begin{minipage}{\sidewaysclen}%
    \centering #1\end{minipage}\end{sideways}}}
\newlength{\finalcolwd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \setlength{\sidewaysclen}{6em}
  \setlength{\finalcolwd}{8.8cm}
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|m{\finalcolwd}|}
    \hline
    \sidewaysc{Rule No}&\sidewaysc{F\_offsetFlag}&
    \sidewaysc{B\_offsetFlag}&
    \sidewaysc{F\_offsetDiff\\ Relation\\ MaxBlkSize}& 
    \sidewaysc{B\_offsetDiff\\ (Relation)\\ MaxBlkSize}&
    \sidewaysc{F\_offsetDiff\\ (Relation)\\ B\_offsetDiff}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Action}}
    \\ \hline
    1     & F     & F     & $<$     &  & =     &
    writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,f\_hash,null);
    \\ \hline
    2     & F     & F     & =     &  & $>$     & 
    \parbox{\finalcolwd}{\raggedright\strut
    If (hasBlockHashOnHBase(next\_b\_hash))\\
      \quad  byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(f\_buf, 0,\\
      \qquad (int)(b\_offset-offset));\\
      \quad  recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null); \\
      Else\\
      \quad  WriteBlockAndUpdateOffsets(f\_buf,\\
      \qquad f\_hash,null);\strut}
    \\ \hline
    3     & F     & F     &       & = & =     &
    \multirow{2}{*}{writeBlockAndUpdateOffsets(b\_buf,b\_hash,null);}
    \\ \cline{1-6} 
    4     & F     & F     &       & = & $>$     &
    \\ \hline
    11    & T     & F     & =     &  & = &
    \multirow{2}{\finalcolwd}[-3pt]{%
      byte[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(b\_buf, 0,\\
      \quad (maxBlockSize-lastBlkSize));\\
      recordBlockAndUpdateOffsets(buf,null,null);\\
      incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets\\
      \quad (f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);}
    \\[4ex] \cline{1-6}
    12    & T     & F     & $>$     &  &       &
    \\[4ex] \hline
    13    & T     & T     & $<$     &  & =     &
    \multirow{2}{\finalcolwd}{%
      incrementBlockAndUpdateOffsets\\
      \quad(f\_hash,f\_BlkSize);} 
    \\ \cline{1-6}
    14    & T     & T     & =     &  & $>$     & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Example table}
  \label{tab:ImplLogic2}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

The table is wide, so I have put it in an `adjust` box, so that it sticks out evenly in to both margins.

Comment: Thank you, Thank You, Thank You... I was trying to solve this by posting in stackOverflow and [stackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131531/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-a-wrap-text-sideways-column-header-in-tabular) Finally i got the complete solution for all the questions. Once again Thanks a lot...